# How to know if an object exist in arraylist or no based on one variable in it

Tags: java, android, arraylist, serialization

I am having array list let's consider it for users . Each user object has a variable called id I tried to use contains methods with the same object exactly but I surprised that it isn't working.. How can I know if the list contains a user with an id that I am looking for without looping on the list elements? I know that I can use loop but I am looking for a better way to do that

Comment: you can do it using stream, `list.stream().filter( o -> o.id == 23).collect(toList())`

Answer (score 1):

Contains in array list is always linear complexity meaning that it always loops through the elements. If you want your contains to work the way you intended you could override equals and make it use the id field in User class. Another way to solve this problem would be to not use array list but HashMap with your ID as a key and a user as value or maybe even a HashSet as it always uses equals before adding elements to the collection.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how to override equals method to use the id

Comment: @Override
public Boolean equals(User other){
  return this.id == other.id;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
public class UserList extends ArrayList<User> {
@Override
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    Object[] arr = this.toArray();
    for (Object obj:arr) {
        if(obj.toString().equals(String.valueOf(o))){
            return  true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}}
class User {
String id;
String name;
@Override
public String toString() {
    return id;
}
```

}

Comment: You have to make custom Arraylist for that class

Answer (score 0):

If you did not override equals in your User class, it will check if it is the same instance, not if the field values are equals. 
If you don't want to override equals, using only the id, you can keep the users in a

```
Map<String,User> users; => users.containsKey(id)
```

where the key is the id, or keep just the ids in a separate

```
Set<String> ids; and call contains. => ids.contains(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, it is possible to iterate the array list to get the answer. If you do not want to do it, you can just copy the values into a hash map like:

```
Map<String, User> userMap = new HashMap();
for (int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++) {
    userMap.put(arrayList.get(i).getId(), arrayList.get(i));
}
String isExist = userMap.containsKey(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to select user with `id=23`, using stream,

```
List<User> usersLlist = New LinkedList<>();
User user;

user = usersLlist.stream().filter( user -> user.id == 23).findAny();
```

if you are using a get method to get user id

```
user = usersLlist.stream().filter( user -> user.getId() == 23).findAny();
```